# How can I save an Excel sheet from R without blank lines?

Tags: r, excel

I'm working with a large matrix which has some lines with blank IDs. And I want to save **only the non.blank lines** in a Excel sheet.

Assuming that the IDs are the first column, this is what I am currently doing:

```
k <- which(is.na(MyData[,1]))
if (length(k) > 0) MyData <- MyData[-k,]
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("MyFolder\\MyFile.xls")
writeWorksheet(wb,data=MyData,sheet=1,header=TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

I don't know why, but the resulting Excel file has the full content of MyData, plus a sequence of blank lines in the same numbers of the blank ID ones.

For example, if MyData has 1000 rows and 5 blank IDs, I get an final MyData with 995 rows. But the final Excel file has those 995 rows **plus 5 blank rows** in the end!

Since I need to submit a **xls** (not xlsx) file with no blank rows, how can I solve it?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the package, but this should work:

```
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("MyFolder\\MyFile.xls")
writeWorksheet(wb,data=MyData[!is.na(MyData$ID), ],sheet=1,header=TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Your code should have worked as both this and your Q should successfully filter the NAs. You may want to see if they are just blank strings instead of NAs. In that case, you'd do:

```
writeWorksheet(wb,data=MyData[MyData$ID != "", ],sheet=1,header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it and the same problem occurs.

Comment: Can you show your data? Maybe ```MyData[is.na(MyData$ID), ]``` and the head of the rest?

Comment: Well, I analyzed and finally solved the problem. The situation was more strange than I thought: as a teste I saved MyData[MyData[,2]==5,] and the resulting sheet had the few rows with 5 in the 2nd column in the top and all the other rows below those!

But this MyData matrix is a result of many commands and operations in other matrices. I tried to apply the !is.na filter in an earlier step and it worked, the problem was solved.

Thanks for try to help.